# How can I get the FileVersion from an Assembly that has been loaded from bytes?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, assemblies

I have some assemblies that are stored in an Oracle BLOB field in a database.  I am loading the assemblies, creating instances of classes, etc. all successfully.  However, I would like to access the AssemblyFileVersion of the loaded assemblies, but can't seem to find out how to do it.

I have tried a number of things, including something like the code below:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(plugInBytes);
var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location).FileVersion;
```

However, when the assembly is loaded from bytes, `assembly.Location` is empty, and nothing good happens after that.

Just looking for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Why you not load it from location when you know the location?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, the location is in an Oracle BLOB field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [`AssemblyFileVersion` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) has been applied, can't you just use:

```
var version = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false)
                      .Cast<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>()
                      .Select(attr => attr.Version)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
if (version != null)
{
    // Got the version number...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try somet

```
 public bool GetVersion(string fileName)
 {
       Assembly asm = null;
       try
       {
               asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
               this._errMsg = err.Message;
               return false;
         }
         if (asm != null)
         {
               this._info = new AssemblyInformation();
               this._info.Name = asm.GetName().Name;
               this._info.Version = asm.GetName().Version.ToString();
              this._info.FullName = asm.GetName().ToString();
         }
         else
         {
               this._errMsg = "Invalid assembly";
               return false;
          } 
          return GetReferenceAssembly(asm);
  }
  public bool GetVersion(Assembly asm)
  {
         if (asm != null)
         {
              this._info = new AssemblyInformation();
              this._info.Name = asm.GetName().Name;
             this._info.Version = asm.GetName().Version.ToString();
             this._info.FullName = asm.GetName().ToString();
         }
         else
          {
             this._errMsg = "Invalid assembly";
             return false;
          }

          return GetReferenceAssembly(asm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the same bytes, save to temporary file and get file version if you need file version. Assembly version is likley to be the same and easier to obtain (see Jon's reply).

Comment: @AlexeiLevnekov, I can't save the assembly to the disk for security reasons